# .NET Settings.Save - File is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server-2012-r2

I've run into a problem running an own tool (.NET 3.5 Client Profile) on Windows Server 2012 R2. The tool is using the singleton Settings object to store program settings.

The user defined tool to store the configuration file is set to `SettingsSingleFileGenerator` - which I guess does not mean anything and just points to the GUI based settings editor?!

When running on any Windows 7 machine as well as running on Windows Server 2012 R2 in elevated mode, storing the settings several times is no problem.

If I run the tool on Windows Server 2012 R2 non-elevated, the first call of `Settings.Default.Save()` is working as expected. With every following call, I get an error message "The process cannot access the file ... because it is being used by another process.".

Using Sysinternals Process Explorer (running elevated), I checked whether the file is actually being used by another process, but only my tool appears.

I could not find any remarks in the documentation that it could be required to somehow close the file after saving. Despite there's no such function as closed given by the `Settings.Default` Instance. There's also no hint that an Exception could be generated when calling `Save()`...

Might be a setting in Windows Server 2012 R2? A security feature? Bug in .NET? I would appreciate any hint to solve that problem ...

Comment: Hmm it would be my guess that the settings file is in use by your app or the anti virus..  the whole "Another process" bit could be a red herring

Comment: I'm quite confused now. Either I did something wrong earlier, but Save() now also does not work in elevated mode.
It's also not possible to catch that exception, so it seems it is caught deep inside the implementation...

Comment: Is this about SQL database(file)?

Comment: This is problem induced by anti-malware.  You'll need to make an exclusion, not so easy to do since the file location is pretty random.  Best to go shopping, I suppose, but ask whomever is responsible for this server to sort it out.

Comment: Well ... I just scrapped the "built in" .NET Settings class and built my own. I'm writing to the same file in the same directory without any problems now...

Comment: Ouch ... argh ... I've just found the cause. I didn't touch the source of that program that long, that I could not remember how the configuration actually worked. I am using an custom settings provider implementation `PortableSettingsProvider` which was missing a `XmlTextWriter.Close()` after writing the file... Darn. This was too simple...